# JWT Passthrough to specific method of api

Tags: php, jwt, slim

From the question above, I have `api/user` that contains `get`, `post`, `put`, and `delete` methods. Is it possible to have `passthrough` on a specific method?

Example, the public method only is get and the rest needs a token to use that method?

Thank you for your answer.

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
"path" => ["/api", "/admin"],
"passthrough" => ["/api/login", "/admin/ping", "/api/user"],
"algorithm" => "HS256",
"secret" => getenv("JWT_SECRET"),
"callback" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) use ($container) {
    $container["jwt"] = $arguments["decoded"];
},
"error" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
    $data["status"] = "error";
    $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
    return $response
        ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [JWT Authentication middleware](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth) does not authenticate `OPTIONS` requests. To also allow unauthenticated `GET` requests you can manually add it to the `RequestMethodRule`. Your example code would become something like following.

```
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$app = new \Slim\App;
$container = $app->getContainer();

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "path" => ["/api"],
    "secret" => getenv("JWT_SECRET"),
    "callback" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) use ($container) {
        $container["jwt"] = $arguments["decoded"];
    },
    "rules" => [
        new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication\RequestMethodRule([
            "passthrough" => ["OPTIONS", "GET"]
        ])
    ],
    "error" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
        $data["status"] = "error";
        $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
        return $response
            ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
]));

$app->get("/api/user", function ($request, $response) {
    print "Hello\n\n";
});

$app->post("/api/user", function ($request, $response) {
    print "Hello\n\n";
});

$app->run();
```

This would yield.

```
$ curl --request GET --include http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.12
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 7

Hello

$ curl --request POST --include http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.12
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 59

{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Token not found"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Slim Middleware](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html) and group authorized routes together and add the middleware to the group:

```
$validateUser = function($request,$response,$next) {
    $token = $_COOKIE['token'];
    $token = JWT::decode($token,$secret,['HS256']);

    if ($token->user->isAdmin) {
        return $next($request,$response);
    }
    return $response->withStatus(403)->withJson(array('message' => 'Forbidden'));
};


$app->get('/api/user',function($request,$response) {
    return $response->withJson(array('message' => 'Public route'));
});

$app->group('/api/user',function() {
    $this->delete('','');
    $this->post('','');
    $this->patch('','');
})->add($validateUser);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i cant get it working. I updated my question and post the code ive been using.